# How to deploy resources of the same type with different properties based on conditions in ARM templates?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

Depending on the resource group, we want to use a **different hosting option for Azure function app** (e.g. DEV: consumption, INT: premium). However, I can't declare the same resource twice in the ARM template. How can I make sure that the correct hosting plan will be deployed based on a given env parameter?

The docs explain how to deploy a resource or NOT, but they do not show how to create resources with different props depending on conditions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/conditional-resource-deployment

I tried the following:

```json
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "condition": "[equals(parameters('skuTier'), 'Dynamic')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('hostingPlanName'), '-', parameters('skuName'))]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "kind": "linux",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[concat(variables('hostingPlanName'), '-', parameters('skuName'))]",
                "computeMode": "Dynamic"
            },
            "sku": {
                "tier": "[parameters('skuTier')]",
                "name": "[variables('skuName')]"
            },
            "tags": {
                "Project": "[parameters('fullProjectName')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "condition": "[equals(parameters('skuTier'), 'ElasticPremium')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('hostingPlanName'), '-', parameters('skuName'))]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "kind": "linux",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[concat(variables('hostingPlanName'), '-', parameters('skuName'))]",
                "workerSize": "[parameters('workerSize')]",
                "workerSizeId": "[parameters('workerSizeId')]",
                "numberOfWorkers": "[parameters('numberOfWorkers')]",
                "reserved": true,
                "maximumElasticWorkerCount": "20"
            },
            "sku": {
                "Tier": "[parameters('skuTier')]",
                "Name": "[variables('skuName')]"
            },
            "tags": {
                "Project": "[parameters('fullProjectName')]"
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new variable which is set based on the condition based on `env` type. Later, use the new variable in resource definition.

For ex (make sure to update the `... set your settings here like below:` section in below example):

```
{
    "variables": {
        "skuInt": {
            ... set your settings here like below:
            "name": "EP1",
            "tier": "ElasticPremium",
            "size": "EP1",
            "family": "EP",
            "capacity": 1
        },
        "skuDev": {
          ... set the various settings here.
        },
        "sku": "[if(equals(parameters('env'),'int'), variables('skuInt'), variables('skuDev'))]",
 }
```

Now use the variable as `"sku": "[variables('sku')]"` as shown below

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('hostingPlanName'), '-', parameters('skuName'))]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "kind": "linux",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[concat(variables('hostingPlanName'), '-', parameters('skuName'))]",
                "workerSize": "[parameters('workerSize')]",
                "workerSizeId": "[parameters('workerSizeId')]",
                "numberOfWorkers": "[parameters('numberOfWorkers')]",
                "reserved": true,
                "maximumElasticWorkerCount": "20"
            },
            "sku": "[variables('sku')]",
            "tags": {
                "Project": "[parameters('fullProjectName')]"
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ah. Excellent. Thanks a lot! I extended that technique for the props as well. @user1672994